# Create address in magento using kasop2 api

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I am able to create a customer using customerCustomerCreate api. But I am not able to create customer address using "customerAddressCreate" api. I am using the below code,

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                env.dotNet = false;
                env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
                env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "login");

                request.addProperty("username", "user");
                request.addProperty("apiKey", "apikey");

                env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
                Object result = env.getResponse();

                Log.e("sessionId", result.toString());




                String sessionId = result.toString();


   request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerAddressCreate");
            request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);

            request.addProperty("customerId",custId);

            SoapObject customerEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerAddressEntityCreate");

            customerEntity.addProperty("city", "bangalore");
            customerEntity.addProperty("company", "outthinking");
            customerEntity.addProperty("country_id", "01");
            customerEntity.addProperty("fax", "08012345");
            customerEntity.addProperty("firstname", "amit");
            customerEntity.addProperty("lastname", "chandra");
            customerEntity.addProperty("middlename", "raj");
            customerEntity.addProperty("postcode", "560007");
            customerEntity.addProperty("prefix", "a");
            customerEntity.addProperty("region_id", 03);
            customerEntity.addProperty("region", "karnataka");
            customerEntity.addProperty("street","Banglore");
            customerEntity.addProperty("suffix", "ac");
            customerEntity.addProperty("telephone", "+91-9962025341");
            customerEntity.addProperty("is_default_billing", false);
            customerEntity.addProperty("is_default_shipping", false);

            request.addProperty("addressdata", customerEntity);
```

It is throwing error

```
SoapFault - faultcode: '100' faultstring: 'Please enter the first name.
    Please enter the last name.
    Please enter the street.
    Please enter the city.
    Please enter the telephone number.
    Please enter the zip/postal code.
    Please enter the country.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
```

Please let me know what wrong I am doing in this code.

Comment: Check out this similar problem here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/52313/231
I think the last line of your code should be `request.addProperty("customerData", customerEntity);` and not `request.addProperty("addressdata", customerEntity);`

Comment: Anna Volks thanks for your reply. I tried what you have mentioned in the reply, but still I am getting same error :(.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Was looking at the wrong soap call. `addressdata` should be right for creating the address.
Have a look if your request matches with the definition of the SOAP API: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customerAddress/customer_address.create.html

Comment: Sorry Anna I followed same link which one you sent, but I am not able to create address using that api. Will you please try that api and let  me know  what changes we need to do please. I need this one very desperately.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not into Android programming. You might try to search for other ksoap api examples here on this platform.